# Visual Studio 2005 uninstall problem

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2010 today. I am using Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 2. Visual Studio 2005 was previously installed in my notebook. I thought that it automatically replaces previous versions. But after successful install of Visual Studio 2010, I can able to find and run Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2010 both. Now I tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2005. But when I am trying to uninstall it from "Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features", an warning message is showing like below:

> Setup is unable to determine a valid ordering for the installation. See the error log for further details.

And after that install is exited. When I am trying to Repair/Reinstall Visual Studio 2005, it pauses in "Generating setup script" (Installing Components showing that "Microsoft Visual 2005" is installing) process (I waited near about 2 hours, but progress bar is not moved). After that I canceled installation wizard.

Now how can I able to uninstall Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: Some of your projects will require changes to build in VS 2010. This can be difficult in some cases. In many others it's easy. If you have a large base of source code projects then you may want to keep both versions on the PC. I would certainly keep them both there until you determine that all your projects convert, build and run properly in VS 2010.

Comment: I already converted all my projects to Visual Studio 2010 (with backup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual uninstall instructions can be found at [Microsoft Support](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310214129/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907965) (KB907965).